# How to set proper jobmanager memory size when zeppelin using yarn-application mode

Tags: apache-zeppelin

When zeppelin using yarn-application mode, how to set proper jobmanager memory size?

For example, when I use default setting in zeppelin-env.sh `ZEPPELIN_INTP_MEM="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m"`, does that means I must give jobmanger memory size more than 1536M, something like `flink.jm.memory=2048`?

Otherwise, I might step into a "Killing container" problem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean yarn-application of flink interpreter. If so, just use the standard flink property `jobmanager.memory.process.size` to set the memory of jobmanager

Comment: is it same as `flink.jm.memory` ? if so, how much to set, 2048?